# php5: Can We Develop Desktop Applications

Tags: php

Can we develop php mysql based desktop applications which dont require browser to run (i.e. runs like java applications).

If so, how?

Comment: You *might* be able to, but that's a very poor idea for so many reasons (one being that the language was explicitly designed for web sites).

Answer (score 4):

[PHP-GTK](http://gtk.php.net/) is most likely going to be your best bet (along with the regular MYSQL stuff).

Answer (score 4):

Sort of.

[PHP-GTK](http://gtk.php.net/) is a project designed to allow PHP applications create client GUIs through GTK. It hasn't been developed for a while, though.

Another approach is deplyoment solutions that bundle a web server and database engine into a deployable product like NuSphere's [PhpDock](http://www.nusphere.com/products/phpdock.htm).

Together with [Mozilla Prism](http://prism.mozillalabs.com/) that provides web browser functionality without all the browser-specific controls and user interface, it may be possible to build standalone PHP applications. How easy those will be to install for the end-user and how fast they will be, is another question.

I would look long and hard whether PHP is the optimal choice for what you want to do. Native Windows, Linux or Mac OS apps are mostly much easier and faster to built using the tools existing for right that purpose. There are also many free tools in that area.

Answer (score 2):

Titanium Appcelerator

http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-desktop-application-development/